# I need a loop in a OLS in matrix form

Tags: r

This is my regression: `Yt= B0 + B1*t + B2*Yt-1`

If I write my matrix:

```
n=1
round(solve(t(X[,c(1, n + 1, n + 4)])%*%X[,c(1, n + 1, n + 4)])%*%t(X[,c(1, n + 1, n + 4)])%*%Y[,n], digits=4)
```

it show me this

```
#      [,1]
#[1,]  0.0920
#[2,] -0.0007
#[3,]  0.4000
```

it is correct for n=1, but I need a code for when n=1, 2, 3

until now I've tried:

```
bh<-array (0,dim=(c(3,20,1)))
for (n in 1:3)
bh[,n] = round(solve(t(X[,c(1, n + 1, n + 4)])%*%X[,c(1, n + 1, n + 4)])%*%t(X[,c(1, n + 1, n + 4)])%*%Y[,n], digits=4)
```

but it says:

> incorrect number of subscribers in the matrix

Comment: You gave `bh` 3 dimensions: 3, 20 and 1. So either omit the last dimension, i.e. `dim=c(3,20)` (the last 1 is not necessary) or add a comma, i.e.  `bh[, n, ] = ...`.

Comment: it works as it should now, i've been progamming so much, that i forgot that komma.

Comment: Well,  that's   comma karma for you :-)